# Django Rest Framework - separate serializer class per method in model based API view

Tags: django-rest-framework

Say I have a simple Django REST Framework view that's extending multiple model classes and serves all the methods in one URL endpoint:

```py
class UserAPIView(RetrieveAPIView, DestroyAPIView, BaseObjectAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_serializer_class(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # return different serializer depending on method??            
        # return UserUpdateSerializer
        return UserViewSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Retrieve user details
        """
        # ...
        return Response(data={'result': "OK"}, status=200)

    def delete(self, request, pk):
        """
        Delete user
        """
        # ...
        return Response(data={'result': "OK"}, status=200)

    def put(self, request, pk):
        """
        Change user
        """
        # ...        
        return Response(data={'result': "OK"}, status=200)
```

Now I need to use different serializers per method, as my get-method will use different fields than my put-method, example serializers:

```py
class UserViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    firstname = serializers.Field(source='firstname')
    lastname = serializers.Field(source='lastname')
    username = serializers.Field(source='username')

    class Meta:
        model = User

class UserUpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    firstname = serializers.Field(source='firstname')
    lastname = serializers.Field(source='lastname')    

    class Meta:
        model = User
```

<s>Is it possible to use different serializers for each method in my model based API view?</s>

**UPDATE:**

I know how to use different serializers inside the methods themselves.

But I need to get the Browsable API generated by Swagger (Django module [rest_framework_swagger](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger)) to retrieve different serializers for each method. 
I can see that loading the API browser page triggers get_serializer_class, but inside that method, I don't know what method Swagger tries to get the serializer for.

How can I get rest_framework_swagger to retrieve different serializers per method?

Answer (score 14):

I think there are at least two ways to achieve this:

1. You simply set the serializer that you want in each of your methods. Like this:

   ```
   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       self.serializer_class = UserViewSerializer
       # ...
       return Response(data={'result': "OK"}, status=200)
   ```
2. You override the *get_Serializer_class* method. Like this:

   ```
   def get_serializer_class(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if self.request.method == 'POST':
           return UserUpdateSerializer
       return UserViewSerializer
   ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I asked the question the wrong way. 
Actually I need the browsable webinterface generated by Swagger to use different serializers per method. But when Swagger fetches the serializer for the API view, there is no way to find out which method Swagger calls get_serializer_class for.
Maybe I'll post a new more specific question

Comment: That's not what he asked, the problem is that browsable API generates HTML forms using the serializer class and can only user one serializer class per endpoint for that.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could use [yaml docstring](http://django-rest-swagger.readthedocs.io/en/latest/yaml.html#serializers) on each method to override serializers. Like:

```
def put(self, request, pk):
    """Change user

    ---
    serializer: .serializers.UserUpdateSerializer
    """
    # ...
    return Response(data={'result': "OK"}, status=200)
```